# A Definition of a Graph Homology

Tags: graph-theory, homology-cohomology, graph-minors

Let $G$ be a graph, and define $C_n$ to be the free abelian group on labeled $K_k$ minors of $G$. We can define a boundary map $\delta_n$ from $C_n$ onto $C_{n - 1}$ by taking a $K_k$ minor and mapping it to the sum of its $K_{k - 1}$ minors times $(-1)^i$ where $i$ is the label of the structure removed. I believe that according to this definition, $\delta_{n - 1} \circ \delta_n = 0$, which states this is a chain complex. Can anyone provide citations for previous research into this homology? I tried to find references to this online but, mostly found only discussions of singular and simplicial homology for graphs as CW-complexes.

This particular homology appears naturally as the first "graph-theoretic" homology rather than a topological homology. In particular, I want to know if it plays nicely with graph homomorphism. If I have two chains for graphs $H, G$ with a homomorphism $\varphi$ between them, will this define an induced $\varphi^*$ between the chains. If not, maybe it would be better to look at the family of homomorphism over minors of $K_k$ into $G$, in which case we can apply the fact that the composition of two homomorphism is a homomorphism. But in this case, it would be much harder to calculate the homology groups. Can we further say that these homologies are isomorphic, in a similar way to singular and simplicial homologies are isomorphic?

Comment: A $K_k$ minor has many $K_{k-1}$ minors, most of which don't correspond to removing a labeled structure. Do you mean to have $\delta_k$ only consider the "straightforward" $K_{k-1}$ minors of $K_k$?

Comment: Yes, I was meaning for $\delta_k$ to only consider the "straightforward" $K_{k- 1}$ minors of $K_k$. I was thinking of the minor relation as labeling the graph $G$ with the vertices of $K_k$, and then considering the boundary map as "forgetting" the vertices associated with each vertex of $K_k$ to get a $K_{k - 1}$ minor.